# How can I test authlogic's current_user in Cucumber?

Tags: cucumber, authlogic

I am trying to use authlogic's test helpers in [Cucumber](https://github.com/aslakhellesoy/cucumber/wiki/), calling activate_authlogic.

Our application_controller has a current_user_session method.

When we drop into the debugger mid-story, `controller` returns a `Authlogic::TestCase::MockController`.

But when we call controller.current_user_session.

The error occurred while evaluating `nil.current_user_session`.

How does this mock suddenly become a nil?

And does this mock controller know about our application controllers' code?

Comment: See this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234920/integration-testing-with-authlogic)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know authlogic (and if this answer is helpful at all), but where does that mock object come from in the first place? You shouldn't be using any mocks in you cucumber stories. Cucumber is like an integration test, testing the complete Rails Stack.

I use it, to make sure, that my view, controller and model specs haven't diverged from each other.