# How do I impersonate a user with AuthLogic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authlogic

I need to be able to create a UserSession without having the decrypted password.

How do I go about doing this?

My current workaround is:

In user.rb

```
def valid_crypted_or_non_crypted_password?(password) 
   valid_password?(password) || password == crypted_password
end
```

In user_session.rb

```
verify_password_method :valid_crypted_or_non_crypted_password?
```

To login

```
UserSession.create(:login => u.login, :password => u.crypted_password)
```

Is there a nicer way to do this?

Comment: Why is it that you do not have the decrypted password? Can't you create the User with a factory before this and be explicit about the password?

Comment: nope, in this case I would like my admin to browse the website pretending to be a different user. or in the case of open id I have the user record but the password is crypted

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://rdoc.info/rdoc/binarylogic/authlogic/blob/73c4cccb38189f0e52e1e362992dfb9db7d1206f/Authlogic/Session/UnauthorizedRecord.html) you can pass a user object to `UserSession.create`.

```
UserSession.create(@some_user)
```

I haven't tried it though.

Comment: Sam, I can't get this working (and detail it here):

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234920/integration-testing-with-authlogic/1332275#1332275

any thoughts on how you got yours working are much appreciated!